# JavaScript - my own document method

Tags: javascript, dom, document

I wrote an own document method and it works. Consider the use of it like this:

```
document.myMethod();
```

How can I dynamically find out what dot notations were used before myMethod?

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].myMethod();
```

I tried `this` but it does not work. Any ideas?

Update: I'm making my own `getElementsByClass('class')`. So I have to know what elements should be checked. `document.myMethod()` should check all of the elements but `document.getElementById('id').myMethod()` only the childs of #id. How do I do that?

Comment: In your second example, `myMethod` will apply to the HTML element, not `document` - it should throw a syntax error if used that way. Does it not?

Comment: What dot notations? Please explain what that means.

Comment: Dot notations is what you see above, the chaining. And it does not throw any errors (jslint). "will apply to the HTML element" that's just what I want. But how can I find out what node that element does have?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `myMethod` does not exist on 'all' DOM `Element`s unless you put it on `Element.prototype` etc, and you really don't want to go down this path.

But if you do, then `this` will refer to the `Element` on which the method is invoked on.

Comment: "you really don't want to go down this path" - see e.g. http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/ for an explanation why.

Answer (score 0):

Chaining dot notation functions is (I think) just syntactic sugar - you're basically calling the last function on the output of the previous function. As far as I'm aware myMethod() would have no way to know what the function was that provided it's input was, unless you provided it as some kind of parameter on the function, for instance:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].myMethod('getElementsByTagName');
```

Why do you want this information?

Comment: I'm making my own getElementsByClass('class'). So I have to know what elements should be checked. document.myMethod() should check all of the elements but document.getElementById('id').myMethod() only the childs of #id. How do I do that?

Comment: Honestly I'm not an expert on that, but I know it's not a straight forward problem - that's why frameworks like jQuery exist :) However if you're determined to do it I'm fairly sure you're going to need to do what's called 'Walking the DOM' using the childNodes and parentNode functions. Check this out for more information: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/intro.html